# Put different containers containing a server in the same server

Tags: apache, docker, debian, reverse-proxy

I have a Debian server with apache2 on it. I can access it by an ip address.

What I want is to be able to access to the containers in it (which contain an apache2 serveur) from the outside by an url like "myIpAddress/container1". What I currently have is an acces to those containers only from the Debian server.

I thought about using proxy reverse, but I cannot make it works.

Thank you for your help! :-)

Comment: are you just looking to access the webserver inside docker container externally via an IP address ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map the docker container's port to a host port and access the docker container from `<host-ip>:port`.

```
docker run -p host-port:container-port image
```

For example, upon running a container using the above command will make the container available at 127.0.0.1

```
 docker run -p 80:5000 training/webapp
```

**Update:**

Setting up reverse proxy using NGINX

This example uses a plain NGINX container as site A and plain Apache server as site B.

1. Run the reverse proxy.

   `docker run -d \
       --name nginx-proxy \
       -p 80:80 \
       -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro jwilder/nginx-proxy`
2. Start the container for site A, specifying the domain name in the VIRTUAL_HOST variable.

   `docker run -d --name site-a -e VIRTUAL_HOST=a.example.com nginx`
3. Check out your website at http://a.example.com.
4. With site A still running, start the container for site B.

   `docker run -d --name site-b -e VIRTUAL_HOST=b.example.com httpd`
5. Check out site B at http://b.example.com.

Note: Make sure you have set up DNS to forward the subdomains to the host running nginx-proxy. If you're using AWS, the easiest way is to use Route53.

For testing locally, map sub-domains to resolve to localhost by adding entries in /etc/hosts file.

```
127.0.0.1    a.example.com

127.0.0.1    b.example.com
```

References

1. [jwilder NGNIX Proxy Github](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy)
2. [NGNIX reverse proxy using docker](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/nginx-reverse-proxy-docker)

Comment: I want to use an url to access my container. An url like myIpAdress/container1

Comment: docker run -p host-port:container-port image will let you do that. Check the updated answer.

Comment: like you said in the answer, I will be able to access my container only by and url like <host-ip>:port. I don't want to have to put the port, only a different argument in the url wich redirect to <host-ip>:port

Comment: If you have a single container, you could bind the container port to host port 80 and just use the ip to access the container as 80 is the default http port.

For multiple containers, you need to have a front-end proxy of some sort to receive the request and forward it to correct container based on the url. (ip/container1)

Nginx is a good choice to be used a front-end proxy. If you are on aws/gcp, load balancer can do this for you.

Comment: check the updated answer. It uses https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy to setup proxying between docker containers.\

Comment: Tank you for the answer! I didn't understood what I have to add to the /etc/hosts file.

Comment: Sorry about introducing the confusion. Adding entries in the /etc/hosts file was to resolve URLs locally. Update your DNS[Route53, Self Hosted DNS server or other DNS solutions] to resolve the subdomains to your IP. I have updated the answer.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the time you spent to help me! If I understood well, after the configuration that you gave to me, I should be able to access a.example.com from the outside of the host like : "ip_of_my_host/a.exemple.com" ?